# Y and Height Values for Stacked Bar Chart in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to render a stacked bar chart from a multidimensional array that is grouped together by stack, and I can't figure out how to configure the y and height values of each rectangle. The tutorial I've been going off is [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208), but their data structure varies greatly from mine. I believe the solution is in how the y0 and y1 values are determined, but being a novice in D3 I'm unable to discern how it's being computed in the tutorial.

Here's what I have so far (the returned data from the data and legendLabels variables is at the top:

```
data = [["Privés dans les trois dimensions","30.2"],["Privés dans une dimension additionelle","24.4"],["Privés seulement dans la dimension spécifiée","8.32"],["Privés dans les trois dimensions","30.2"],["Privés dans une dimension additionelle","26.1"],["Privés seulement dans la dimension spécifiée","3.75"],["Privés dans les trois dimensions","30.2"],["Privés dans une dimension additionelle","33.1"],["Privés seulement dans la dimension spécifiée","10.4"]]

legendLabels = ["Nutrition","Santé","Eau"];


var $chart = $(chart),
    data = $chart.data("chartDataTest"),
    legendLabels = $chart.data("chartLabels"),
    groupedData = [];

$.each(legendLabels, function(i){
  var labelLength = legendLabels.length,
      dataLength = data.length;

  var sliceBeginning = i * labelLength,
      sliceEnd = sliceBeginning + labelLength;
      dataRange = data.slice(sliceBeginning, sliceEnd);

  groupedData.push(dataRange);
});

var yValues = [];

$.each(groupedData, function(i, dataGroup){
  var subGroupY = 0;
  $.each(dataGroup, function(ii, dataSubGroup){
    subGroupY += +dataSubGroup[1];
  });
  yValues.push(subGroupY);
});

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select(chart).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("class", "parent-group")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain(legendLabels.map(function(d) { return d; }));
x0.domain(groupedData.map(function(d) { return d; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(yValues, function(d) { return d; })]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

var group = svg
  .selectAll(".group")
  .data(groupedData)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d) + ",0)";
  });

var yPosition = 0;

group
  .selectAll(".group")
  .data(function(d) { return d; })
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return y(d[1]);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return y(d[1]);
  });
```

Here's what my chart looks like so far:

[image]

Comment: Did you work carefully through the entry in the docs [***here***](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Stack-Layout)?

Comment: @CoolBlue the tutorial I was using didn't use the stack function and opted to use a forEach loop instead, so I was hoping for an answer along those lines. I can give stack a shot and report back

Comment: I think that's a good idea, there's so many common problems already solved in d3, it's worth the effort to dig it out and use it. And hopefully, that part of the docs is reasonably ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @CoolBlue's suggestion, I rerefactored this to use d3's `stack` function. I based my new approach on [this tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/anotherjavadude/2940908). Here's the updated code:

```
var $chart = $(chart),
    data = $chart.data("chartDataTest"),
    chartStacks = $chart.data("chartLabels"),
    groupedData = [],
    colors = [];


var width = 900,
    height = 500,
    margin = { top: 10, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]),
    x0 = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width - margin.left - margin.right], 0.1),
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, height - margin.top - margin.bottom]);
    y0 = d3.scale.linear().range([height - margin.top - margin.bottom, 0]);


var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x0)
      .orient("bottom"),
    yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y0)
      .orient("left")
      .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));


$.each(chartStacks, function(i){
  var labelLength = chartStacks.length,
      dataLength = data.length;

  var sliceBeginning = i,
      dataRange = data.slice(sliceBeginning);

  colorGroup = [];

  $.each(dataRange, function(ii, colorData){

    if ( ii % labelLength == 0) {
      colorGroup.push(colorData[1]);
    }
  });

  var remappedValues = colorGroup.map(function(dat, i) {
      return {
        x: i,
        y: +dat
      }
  });

  var remappedColors = dataRange.map(function(dat, i) {
      return dat[0];
  });

  colors.push(remappedColors[0]);
  groupedData.push(remappedValues);
});

var stacked = d3.layout.stack()(groupedData);

x0.domain(chartStacks.map(function(d) { return d; }));
x.domain(stacked[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(stacked[stacked.length - 1], function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);
y0.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return 90; })]);

var svg = d3.select(chart).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);


svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ", " + 46 + ")")
    .call(yAxis);

var svgContent = svg
  .append("g")
    .attr("class", "parent-group")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + height + ")");

var valGroup = svgContent
  .selectAll(".parent-group")
  .data(stacked)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "valgroup");

var rect = valGroup.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d){return d;})
  .enter().append("svg:rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return -y(d.y0) - y(d.y); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand() - 15);
```